# Spring boot JSP configuration not working

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, spring-mvc

I followed the sample Git setup here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp.

When I load the home page it displays `resource could not be found`. Even when I've cross-checked my configuration and the only difference between the two projects is that one is multi-module, while the other is single module.

And it worked, but for my multi-module maven project the same configuration seems to not be working... is there any explanation to this? I'm also kind of new to maven so I'm assuming it has something to do with the way I have my maven setup configured. The link to my GitHub repo is: https://github.com/diljotr/storm.net.

Relevant links to look at are:
https://github.com/diljotr/storm.net/blob/master/storm.net.app/src/main/java/storm/net/Application.java
https://github.com/diljotr/storm.net/blob/master/storm.net.web/src/main/java/storm/net/controller/HomeController.java
https://github.com/diljotr/storm.net/blob/master/storm.net.web/src/main/java/storm/net/WebApplication.java

Setup outlined below

---

Parent POM:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>storm.net</groupId>
    <artifactId>storm.net</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <modules>
        <module>storm.net.api</module>
        <module>storm.net.core</module>
        <module>storm.net.web</module>
        <module>storm.net.app</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <tomcat.version>7.0.53</tomcat.version>

        <!-- Spring Boot build configuration -->
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <start-class>storm.net.Application</start-class>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

---

Web Child POM:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>storm.net</artifactId>
        <groupId>storm.net</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>storm.net.web</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

</project>
```

---

App POM that wraps the entire library together

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>storm.net</artifactId>
        <groupId>storm.net</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>storm.net.app</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>storm.net</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm.net.core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>storm.net</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm.net.web</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

---

Comment: "Not working"? Be specific.

Comment: You're right sorry, when I load the home page it displays `resource could not be found`. Even when I've cross-checked my configuration and the only difference between the two projects is that one is multi-module, while the other is single module.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below Configuration  :

In Intellij:
    Go to **Run** Menu -> Edit Configuration  -> Working directory: $MODULE_WORKING_DIR$

spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp